# Make object visual size constant despite the distance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scale, distance

[Visual aid here](https://ibb.co/k28xZb)

Please see visual aid. Following the gif, there are two GUIs. The GUI on the left is scaling properly based on the cameras distance to the object. The GUI on the right is scaling, seen clearly in the 'Scene' view, but not even noticeable in game view. The application is for the Hololens as the users head controls the camera within the Unity scene.

The problem lies in  setting the objects scaling. Been racking my brain all day trying to replicate the type of scaling shown on the left GUI. Dividing the distance and using this as the factor to scale by is clearly incorrect as the object is either far too large and grows too fast, or far too small and grows too slowly but I don't know how to meet somewhere in the middle. Scaling in both directions equally at a noticeable yet not obnoxiously large or imperceptible rate.

Implementation code thus far:

```
// GameObject and GUI assigned in Editor
public GameObject sphere, rotationManager;

// For rotationManager scaling
private float cameraToObject,

void Update()
{
    /* Scale rotationManager based on Cameras distance to object */
    cameraToObject = Vector3.Distance(
        sphere.transform.position, 
        Camera.main.transform.position);

    Debug.Log("distance: " + cameraToObject);

    // If camera isn't too close to our object
    if (cameraToObject > 4f)
    {
        // adjust scale
        rotationManager.transform.localScale = new Vector3(
            cameraToObject / 5, 
            cameraToObject / 5, 
            rotationManager.localScale.z);

        // enable rotationManager
        rotationManager.gameObject.SetActive(true);

    }
    // Camera is too close, turn off GUI
    else
        rotationManager.gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: The reason its not noticeable in the game view *is the intended goal* when you're doing something like this: the reason it doesn't look like its scaling is because it's *closer to the camera* which makes it appear *larger* and additionally it's scaled down *by the same amount.* `x * (1 / x)`

Comment: @Draco18s If I'm only scaling X&Y how is it getting closer to the camera? Wouldn't Z scaling and/or positioning induce that effect.. I tried scaling Z as well and I couldn't get the desired behavior either

Comment: The camera is moving. It's attached to your head. :|

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really sure what you are doing wrong, as dividing distance by constant must give required effect. Anyway try this code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class AutoSize : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float FixedSize = .005f;
    public Camera Camera;

    void Update ()
    {
        var distance = (Camera.transform.position - transform.position).magnitude;
        var size = distance * FixedSize * Camera.fieldOfView;
        transform.localScale = Vector3.one * size;
        transform.forward = transform.position - Camera.transform.position;
    }
}
```

It seems to work fine - [preview](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zs2hqyag5y248b9/2017-12-10_23-57-31.mp4?dl=0)

Also maybe it will be more effective to create constant menu size and just position it by converting world space to the screen space.

Comment: `transform.position =
                (Camera.main.transform.position - sphere.transform.position) / 2f;`

Comment: @jtth In your case you have got half of the direction heading from the camera to the sphere. You should summ positions, not subtract. center = (pos0 + pos1) / 2.

Comment: Magnifique Victor, Merci.

Comment: Seme a bit unnecessary, why not just do it in a shader instead?