# How to make Unity Game fit any resolution when resizing the window?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, window-resize

I couldn't find an option to send a picture to better explain what's happening. [Here's](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1640823/how-to-make-unity-game-fit-any-resolution-when-res.html) a Unity Link that has the photos to explain the issue.

I've tried `Camera.main.orthographicsize = 4.0f`, a solid number to stay on but the Orthographic Size of the camera keeps changing it's size after resizing the window when I'm in free aspect Unity editor mode and even when I export the Unity game with 1920x1080(16:9) resolution. I want it to stay the same size when resizing the window so that the game can always fit inside the screen in any resolution when resizing the window. The default blue background of the camera displays when I stretch the window's width far enough which I don't want to happen.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYNF5PifSmA&list=PLuNkJO3aA7nx8-p1Gj78-Yldz3r7b4By1&index=2) Youtube video has the results I'm looking for but the code unfortunately is not working on Unity 2019. The code provided from this video does entirely different things for me and doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: This is not the best way to post a question, do not link this question to unity's QA site, improve formatting.

Comment: Post the code, make it simple, summarize the problem.

Comment: I suggest you to set *aspect* of the scene to a fixed resolution.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood is that the screen has to has a fixed resolution.

This link will demonstrate the solution. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GameView.html

It does that by changing the
*Game View Aspect* from free to a fixed resolution.

> **Unless this is not what you are looking for** then I sugest another solution:
>
> Make a black background image that fits the screen size.
>   Then change the scale of the objects in the scene relative to the camera.
>
> This link will make the scaling solution, [Make object visual size constant despite the distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47723316/make-object-visual-size-constant-despite-the-distance)

Comment: Thanks for the response but the images are already constant but the camera orthographic size is not. I also have the game support different aspect ratios from the player settings.before I build the game. In the youtube video it better explains what I'm already explaining I'm having an issue with.